# It's wrong making a new question of an older question looking for updated answers?

Tags: discussion, old-questions, old-answers

I've found several answers to my question, but those answers are old, the lastest post is a question from 2008 and the last answer is from 2012. I suppose there can be a new answer for this question because are related to SQL 2000, but I'm not sure if is wrong asking the same, asking for an updated answer, with the original question in related.

Should I ask the same, and adding a reference?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: Why exactly do you think the old answers are no longer good enough? Also see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258363 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287381

Comment: Because the answer that I found is a "workaround" for a SQL200 version, and maybe there is a patch for SQL 2014

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the other post.  This is much more specific.  I too have this question, with regards to ten (or so) year old security questions -- e.g. "what's the best way to implement a password reset".  The answers may have been GREAT back in 2009, but best practices change over time.  Maybe in 2015 somebody totally broke that "best" method and it's no longer a good answer. So what's the best way to "re-up" an old but common question and get answers relevant to today's methods? (and NOT have it muddied up with old answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a bounty if you want to draw attention to an older question in an attempt to get higher quality answers than it currently has.

Comment: Thanks! I think it about, but the question it was for an old version and I was concerned if new answers will be for the same version and not a new one. I think edit the question is not ethical (is not mine)

Comment: @Leandro You don't need to edit the question, you just need to add a bounty, and you're done.

Answer (score 4):

A new well researched question could be fine in certain cases.

Firstly, you should always reference similar questions that you've looked at in your question and state why you think the outdated answers aren't suitable. If links to these posts are in the questions and you've covered the content in them, then there is less reason for someone to close as a duplicate.

Also, you could be using language features that aren't available in earlier/later versions. As long as you can highlight and justify the differences that can separate the posts, then I think it's acceptable.

The most you can do is show effort on your part to ask a well formulated question.

Comment: The OP gave no indication that the existing answers aren't working for him.

Comment: Having an accepted answer in no way prevents a bounty from being posted.  That he wants an "updated" answer doesn't mean what's there doesn't work, just that he wonders if there might be a better way to do it using newer features.